NetSuite > Render HTML template to Suitelet > How to pass array as dropdown values of select field
I have a NetSuite Suitelet that will render the page using an HTML file, with a data source coming in within the Suitelet:
var renderer = render.create();
renderer.templateContent = file.load(<file id>).getContents();
renderer.addCustomDataSource({format:render.DataSource.OBJECT, alias:"DATA", data: DATA});
renderer.renderToResponse({response:scriptContext.response});

In the HTML code, there are 2 select fields which should list down transaction numbers from NetSuite:
<select id="workorderIDInput" name="workorderIDInput">
   <option value="">Select a Work Order</option>
</select>

I wanted to use a search in the Suitelet, and have the search results to be used in the HTML as select options. I am already gathering the transaction numbers via search, and adding that array to the "DATA" data source of the renderer:
var workorders = loadWorkOrders();

function loadWorkOrders(scriptContext){

    try {

        var workOrderIds = [];
        var searchId = 6427;
        // var currentScript = runtime.getCurrentScript();
        // var searchId = currentScript.getParameter({
        //  name: 'custscript_wo_search_id'
        // });
        var woSearch = search.load({
            id: searchId
        });
        woSearch.run().each(function(result){

            var woTranNum = result.getValue('tranid');
            workOrderIds.push(woTranNum);
            return true;

        });

        // log.debug('Work Order IDs', workOrderIds);

        return workOrderIds;

    } catch (e) {

        log.error('loadWorkOrders error', e);

    }
}

Is this possible to achieve? There is another approach where I will be calling an endpoint to give the array and loop through and create option elements from chatGPT, but I'm still trying to make it work. This question seems to be on the direct approach without creating a separate endpoint to get the values I need for the dropdown
There is another approach where I will be calling an endpoint to give the array and loop through and create option elements from chatGPT, but I'm still trying to make it work. This question seems to be on the direct approach without creating a separate endpoint to get the values I need for the dropdown

You can certainly do what you are asking though what you describe will be a fairly static page (re-rendered on every select?)
When embedding complex UIs in NetSuite I generally create a react app and embed that. See React JS and Suitelet
Then the react app calls back to the suitelet (same origin and root url) with an  'action' query parameter for all the AJAX calls.
You move a great deal of the interaction to 'normal' UI work this way.
